# Java: How to add static text to file using ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java

i am developing a small application in Java. At certain point i need to save the object of my custom class to a text file for this i override `toString()` method in my custom class and then use `ObjectOutputStream` class to save object of my custom class to text file. Now everything works fine i.e the text file contains the text as expected. Following three lines contain major code for that

```
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
outputStream.writeObject(person);//person is the instance of my custom class
```

Now, how do i add some static data to my file along with the object data

```
outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
outputStream.WhatFunctoinToUse("some static text");//What function i use to add static text??
outputStream.writeObject(person);//person is the instance of my custom class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append a primitive type value to be flattened with an Object, pass your `ObjectOutputStream` to `PrintStream` to enable you append a new line which will effect hold the `static` value as require.

See below for both Reading and writing.

```
    //Writting
    ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("person.out"));
    outputStream.writeObject(person);
    PrintStream pst = new PrintStream(outputStream);
    pst.append("Some static Value");

    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    pst.close();

    // Reading
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("person.out"));
    Perrson person=(Person) in.readObject();
    String staticText =in.readLine(); 
    in.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You don't.

`ObjectOutputStream` is not meant to be used in that fashion. It outputs a `Serializable` object in a format specified by the API. This is not always a good idea, i.e. it is easy to break compatibility in future releases.

Although the format outputted looks readable, it contains a lot of non-printable characters, that adding some static text to probably would break the serialization.

What you are looking for is either:

a) A clear-text serialization such as JSON or XML (Try http://simple.sourceforge.net/, it's really simple)

b) A text file besides your serialized object.

You should NOT try to extend the functionality of the `ObjectOutputStream` unless you have a very very good reason for it, and it does not seem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you realise that by making use of ObjectOutputStream and writing `person` to it, you're in essence serializing the `person` object.